# Print all SubStrings of an Array in a 2-D Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, substring

I am a beginner in Java and very new to StackOverflow.

I have to write a program that asks the user for Words then prints out all the words in a Single dimension Array and Then Print out all the Substrings of each word from that array in a 2-dimensional array (each word on a separate row.)

When the program is run it asks the user for the number of words. and then asks the user to enter all the words **All the words must be equal length(**rectangular 2d array only**)

This is my code its not working it doesnt print the 2d array pls help.

```
    //Ari
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class twoDArrays
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {



        String totalWords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How Many Words?");
        int val = Integer.parseInt(totalWords);

        String[] words = new String[val];

        for (int i =0; i<val; i++)
        {
            words[i]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Words");
            System.out.print(words[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        int len = words[0].length();

        int subs = ((len)*(len+1))/2;

        String table [][] = new String[val][subs];

        for(int i=0; i<val; i++)
        {
            String [] temp = totalSubs(words[i]);
            for (int a = 0; a <subs; a++)
            {  
                table[i][a] = temp[a];
            }
        }
        for (int i= 0; i < table.length; i++)   
        {
            System.out.print(words[i] + " ");
            for (int a = 0; a< subs; a++)
            {
                System.out.print(table[i][a] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static String[] totalSubs(String s1)
    {
        int length = s1.length();
        int num = ((length)*(length+1))/2;
        String[] sub = new String[num];
        int loop=0;
        int b =0;
        int pos = 0;
        while(loop < num)
        {
            int a=0;
            for(int i = pos; i < length; i++ )
            {
                if((a+1) < (length +b))
                {
                    sub[loop] = s1.substring(pos, (a + 1 + b));
                    loop++;
                    a++;
                }
            }
            pos++;
            b++;
        }
        return sub;
    }

}
```

This is how it should work

When u Run the Program it ask u for the number of words u want to enter.
Then it asks to enter all the words. (all words to be same length).
When u enter all the words it prints out all the words u entered in an 1-D array.
ex: **cat dog mom dad**
Then 2nd part of the program prints out all the Susbtring of each word in a 2 dimesional array (each word on a different row.)
ex:

- c ca cat a at t
- d do dog o og g
- m mo mom o om m
- d da dad a ad d

Thanks for Help if anyone can help I am new to this.

Comment: The problem is in your `totalSubs()`, which loops forever. Try calling with `totalSubs("AB")` and step through the code with a debugger. You'll find that it adds `"A"`, then `"B"` to the result array, but never adds `"AB"`, so it loops forever, since result array is never filled.

Comment: Bro most of the things u said i dont understand i am learning java from 1 month. i have no other experience. Also i dont know how to debug. Can u edit it inside my code?

Comment: also give line #'s pls i am new to this

Comment: I linked to instructions about debugging, told you symptom of what is wrong to help get you started. Fixing the code is your job as a programmer. I gave a small 2-letter example to help you, so you can go through the code on paper, if needed, until you find out why it doesn't come up with a 2-letter result, i.e. only `"A"` and `"B"`, but not `"AB"`.